# What is the source of this text?

Tags: blessing, shemoneh-esrei

At the end of Elokai Nitzor we say:

"עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן שְׁמֶֽךָ עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן יְמִינֶֽךָ עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן קְדֻשָּׁתֶֽךָ עֲשֵׂה לְמַֽעַן תּוֹרָתֶֽךָ"

Is there a source for these sentences? The reason I ask, rather than assume it was just written and instituted by the Rabbis (although perhaps that is the answer?) is because the paragraph as a whole comes from [Brachot 17](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.17a?lang=bi) (however this line does not appear there) and the sentence after it ends (starting with "L'maan") comes from Tehillim (it appears in both Tehillim [60](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16281/jewish/Chapter-60.htm?gclid=Cj0KCQjwvYSEBhDjARIsAJMn0lg-61ir6kOISWX-Uon1fnjDDA653AzWLdswo7FTD7FCuABS5aCYdBgaAtXDEALw_wcB) and [108](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16329/jewish/Chapter-108.htm)). Therefore, due to the nature of the paragraph, I thought perhaps this line too is sources from somewhere. Thank you!

Comment: See the tur 122

Comment: See [Jer 14:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.14.7?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi).

Comment: @magicker72 that seems to just be the same words (i.e., it doesn't have the rest) None of the siddurs I use source that pasuk, either.

Answer (score 9):

In their essay in Hebrew "[The Section "Malkeinu Elokeinu" at the End of the Prayer of Shemoneh Esreh and Birkat Hamazon: Its Origin, Form and Status](https://www.ybz.org.il/?CategoryID=282&ArticleID=3697&dbsAuthToken=#.YIJjC-gzZPY)", [Uri Ehrlich](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9A) and [Avi Schmidman](https://www.yehee.co.il/artist/%D7%90%D7%91%D7%99-%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%9F/) trace the verse "עשה למען שמך וכו'" to a section that used to be said at the end of prayer called "Malkeinu Elokeinu":

> מלכינו אלהינו יחד שמך בעולמך יחד זכרך בעולמך. בנה ביתך שכלל היכלך קרב משיחך שמח עדתך שכינתך תשיב לבית מקדשך. עשה למען שמך עשה למען תורתך עשה למען מלכותך עשה למען משיח צדקך עשה למענך ולא למענינו.‏

This section, in turn, they trace to an ancient text that was part of the Hechalot literature which describes a meeting of the author with an angel:

> ואמרתי לו אלופי, עזרי ומפלטי דרך ישרים הודיעני. ואמר לי שאל ואתן לך. ואמרתי לו במה יזכי אדם את עצמו ויהא בן העולם הבא? ואמר לי כל האומר בתפילתו ובברכת המזון יחיד שמך בעולמך יחיד מלכותך בעולמך בנה ביתך עשה למען שמך ושכליל היכלך עשה למען (למען) ימינך מובטח לו שבן העולם הבא הוא.‏

This attribution of the verse to an angel is mentioned also in two manuscripts of [Rabbi Asher ben Yaakov Halevi of Ossenbrügge](https://www.jstor.org/stable/23538314?read-now=1&refreqid=excelsior%3A2fa062d60184fe957d1b87dcddb3c358&seq=4#page_scan_tab_contents)'s commentary on the prayer (fol. [86](https://www.nli.org.il/he/manuscripts/NNL_ALEPH000191696/NLI#$FL36461255)-[87](https://www.nli.org.il/he/manuscripts/NNL_ALEPH000191696/NLI#$FL36461266) in the NLI's site or pg. 89-90 [here](http://real-ms.mtak.hu/578/1/Kaufmann_Ms_A399.pdf)<sup>1</sup>):

> שמעתי שיש בספר היכלות שאמ' המלאך לר' ישמעאל כהן גדול לכשתבא לסיים תפלתך עד יהיו לרצון אמרי פי יש לך לומר מלכינו אלהינו יחיד שמך בעולמך פדה עמך בנה עירך שכלל היכלך עשה למען שמך עשה למען ימינך עשה למען בריתך עש' למען תורתך עשה למען היכלך עשה למען משיח צדקך עשה למענך אם לא למענינו יהיו לרצון אמרי פי וכו' ומסיים תפילתו.‏

[Ra'avan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_ben_Nathan) in [Sefer Hamanhig](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8912&st=&pgnum=30), on the other hand, sourced it to the amora Shmuel:

> מצאתי אמ<ר> שמואל כל האומ<ר> אחר תפי<לתו> אלו ג' דברים עשה למען שמך עשה למען ימינך עשה למען משיח צדקך אין תפי<לתו> חוזרת ריקם. אב"ן. ומנהגינו לומ<ר> מלכינו אלהינו יחד שמך בעולמך בנה ביתך שכלל היכלך קרב קץ ביאת משיחך עשה למען שמך עשה למען ימינך עשה למען משיח צדקך עשה למען יחלצון ידידיך הושיעה ימינך וענני אלהי נצור, וי"א אלהי עד שלא נוצרתי.‏

---

<sup>1</sup> Thank you @Kazibácsi for tracking down the MS and the relevant section.

Comment: As mentioned in the footnote, it is there in the [Kaufmann A399](http://real-ms.mtak.hu/578) p. 90 (in the PDF), but it's missing from the [Huntington 404/Neubauer 794](https://digital.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/objects/2957cdd7-08d4-43ea-a51c-15f4ba22995f/surfaces/95d511e4-f8b2-479c-9f9c-04bf018081d4/) 48v. BTW, what is MS Oxford 1102 and which manuscript is mentioned [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21968&st=&pgnum=168) in the footnote?

Comment: @Kazibácsi According to Neubauer's list, it should be MS Oppenheim 649, but that isn't listed in the Bodleian's digitalized Hebrew MSS site [here](http://bav.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/digitized-items-hebrew-manuscripts).

Comment: This section is still printed in its entirety (often in parentheses) in some siddurim

Comment: BTW, the cited text is there in R' Amram's siddur https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43020&pgnum=25